# Efficient sparse linear interpolation of row by row data

Tags: r, data.table

What is the most efficient way to do linear interpolation when the desired interpolation points are sparse compared to the available data? I have a very long data frame containing many columns, one of which represents a timestamp and the rest are variables, for which I am interested in interpolating at a very small number of timestamps. For example, consider the two variable case:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(approx(1:2, 1:2, 1.5)$y)
# Unit: microseconds
# expr    min      lq     mean median      uq     max neval
# ...  39.629 41.3395 46.80514 42.195 52.8865 138.558   100

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(approx(seq_len(1e6), seq_len(1e6), 1.5)$y)
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# ...   129.5733 231.0047 229.3459 236.3845 247.3096 369.4621   100
```

we see that although only one interpolated value (at `t = 1.5`) is desired, increasing the number of pairs `(x, y)` can cause a few orders of magnitude difference in running time.

Another example, this time with a data table.

```
library(data.table)
tmp_dt <- data.table(time = seq_len(1e7), a = seq_len(1e7), b = seq_len(1e7), c = seq_len(1e7))
```

Running `tmp_dt[, lapply(.SD, function(col) {approx(time, col, 1.5)$y}), .SDcols = c("a", "b", "c")]` produces a one row data table but it takes a while.

I am thinking there must be some efficiency to be gained by removing all rows in the data table that are not necessary for interpolation.

Comment: If linear interpolation only uses the two closest points in either direction (?), then you can do two rolling joins or sort and use findInterval to find those two points and do the calculation, I suppose. For the rolling join, you cannot join float on integer, however...

Comment: linear interpolation only requires the two closest points in either direction.

Answer (score 2):

If your linear interpolation is `weighted.mean(c(x0, x1), c(t1-t, t-t0))`, where `(t0, x0)` is the nearest point below and `(t1, x1)` the nearest above...

```
# fix bad format
tmp_dt[, names(tmp_dt) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric)]

# enumerate target times
tDT = data.table(t = seq(1.5, 100.5, by=.5))

# handle perfect matches
tDT[, a := tmp_dt[.SD, on=.(time = t), x.a]]

# handle interpolation
tDT[is.na(a), a := {
  w  = findInterval(t, tmp_dt$time)
  cbind(tmp_dt[w, .(t0 = time, a0 = a)], tmp_dt[w+1L, .(t1 = time, a1 = a)])[, 
    (a0*(t1-t) + a1*(t-t0))/(t1-t0)]
}]
```

The extension to more columns is a little messy, but can be shoehorned in here.

Some sort of rolling, like `w = tmp_dt[t, on=.(time), roll=TRUE, which=TRUE]`, might be faster than `findInterval`, but I haven't looked into it.